# Detection of Error in react js when a component loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project what i want to know is how to detect if there is  a error in the component and redirect to home page or show a page to redirect on the home page in case of error . programmatically

Comment: Use `ErrorBoundary`

Comment: You may want to read the official docs on how to handle this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#error-boundaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `ErrorBoundary` and wrap your component inside the `ErrorBoundary`. Inside the `componentDidCatch` in the `ErrorBoundary` component, you can load the home page or you can render the appropriate message and link to go back to home page.

Your `ErrorBoundary` should look like following.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
    console.log(error, info);
  }
  //Render the error condition component
  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h1>Unable to load this section of the page!!</h1>;
    } else {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }
}
ErrorBoundary.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object
};
export default ErrorBoundary;
```

And wrap your component inside your error boundary like following.

```
 <ErrorBoundary>
     <MyComponent={props} />
 </ErrorBoundary>
```

You can read more about `ErrorBoundary` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#error-boundaries)

Comment: Thank you will read the documentation and implement .. will get back you you if i get any major speed bumps

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ‘componentdidcatch()’ life cycle method here.